# Custom Directory Image

Tags: android

I'm currently trying to figure out how to set a custom image for a external storage directory I'm creating some time in the app. If you're probably using a file browser like ES File Explorer you will see that some apps like WhatsApp but also smaller projects have an extra little picture or app logo added to their folder.

Is this possible to set by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set one that other apps use.  There's no such concept as an image for a directory.  Inside your own app you can do whatever you want, you have to write any file explorer yourself.